# d3jsv4 brush on timeline bug

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am converting an old d3v3 timeline to v4 - but I am getting a bug now with the brush

```
Error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/173/

```
var brush = d3.brushX()
                //.x(x)
                .on("brush", display);
```

These appear undefined?

```
minExtent = brush.extent()[0],
maxExtent = brush.extent()[1],
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_extent): `If extent is specified, sets the brushable extent to the specified array of points [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]]`, looks like you are passing an array but it wants an array of arrays...

Comment: Oh and also, this `minExtent = brush.extent()[0],` is a no-go too.  The brush functionality changed significantly in version 4 and it no longer holds its own state.  You need to read [this](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#brushes-d3-brush).

Comment: So would it be --- var brush = d3.brushX()
            .extent([[0, 0], [w, miniHeight]])
      .on("brush", display);

Comment: @Mark - this was the old code base v3 -- http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/rajvansia/ce6903fad978d20773c41ee34bf6735c

Comment: Ok - so I can see the brush is now drawn correctly - but how do I reapply the functionality -- if there is extent code? -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/177/

Comment: -- I've got some console logs going on -- @Mark http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/178/

Comment: -- @Mark http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/179/ - I think I got it working -- how do I auto select the brush at the start -- so I would call brushed.. but how would I create a small initial block?